# Joomla asks xcache password all the time

Tags: php, joomla3.0, xcache

I have a website built on Joomla 3. I am running it on PHP 5.3.3. on a shared host. 
Now every now and then the system asks for a xcache username and password.

When installing the site i wasn't asked to install or configure xcache.

In the configuration in Joomla:

Caching is set to: OFF -Caching disabled
Cache Handler is xcache

So any idea's why the system is asking for xcache username and password?
How can I disable this / get rid of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear in your question, but I assume that not Joomla itself asks for credentials but the server.

If you have caching disabled, what is the point of configuring xcache? Just use filesystem.

It looks like xcache is not properly configured, maybe Joomla is calling a function like a garbage collector or something (and this is an explanation why this occurs from time to time) - just a hunch.

I don't know if on your share host can do that, but ideally you would set the user / password in xcache.ini.

Hope this helps!